# Copy iOS App bundle to another folder during Xcode build

Tags: macos, xcode4

I would like to copy the contents of my iOS App Bundle to a particular directory during the Xcode build stage.  Can anyone tell me how to do that?

Comment: You say 'mac' but you've tagged your question as 'ios'?

Comment: Your question still says 'mac' and is still tagged 'ios'.  Your question makes no sense at all.

Comment: well u can only develop ios apps in mac remember?!

Comment: OK, so you want to build an app and then copy the contents of the app bundle to somewhere, other than the build folder?

Comment: nope, i wanna copy contents of my application's main bundle to a particular location in mac.

Comment: When? During the build in Xcode?

Comment: yeah!!
Just like we can copy the contents to the documents directory, similarly can you choose another location to copy?

Comment: Create a shell script and add it as a build step.

Comment: so everytime it builds it will run the script.. ohk. thanx!!

Answer (score 1):

A solution using a script in "Build Phases" does not work properly since Xcode is not finished building the app when running the script. Here is a solution with a script that runs after all build tasks are finished:

1. Go to "Edit Scheme"
2. Click on the triangle next to "Build"
3. Select "Post-action"
4. Press the + button and select "New Run Script Option"
5. Select your app name in "Provide build settings from"
6. Add the following shell script:

Script:

```
PRODUCT="${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}.app"
cp -R "${PRODUCT}" ~/Desktop
```

[image: Edit Schemes]